# How can I inspect physics simulation data as it changes from frame to frame?

Tags: animation, physics

If I run a cloth simulation (or any other simulation), how can I inspect the physics data such as spring tension along the cloth as it changes over time?

I am wondering if it is possible to store the simulation data after pressing the Render/Animate button. I want to be able to pull the data out and use it in Python scripting.

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15577/how-to-extract-convert-data-from-blender-cache-files-bphys-into-a-human-readabl)